# Payment Action "Authorize and Capture" not completing order

Tags: magento

I have created a module for new payment method.

I have added options to select Payment Action. For "Authorize Only" it is working fine but "Authorize and Capture" is not working as expected on Magento EE.10.0.0. 
Order status should be "complete" but it is "pending" after order is placed successfully.

However, It is working fine on Magento EE.10.1.0.

Any guesses??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge on 'Authorize and Capture' the order status should change to 'processing' (default).

But you normally can change this workflow, take a look your admin setting in `System -> Config -> Payment Methods -> 'Your Payment Method'` then `New Order Status/Order Status`.

After on order have been ship then the status change to 'complete', take a look @

- [How do i make auto shipping programatically in magento?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14983522/how-do-i-make-auto-shipping-programatically-in-magento)
- [How to create shipping automatically in Magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13412333/how-to-create-shipping-automatically-in-magento)

Comment: Yes, you are right. On 'Authorize and Capture' the order status changes 'processing'. It was my mistake, when I was testing it on Magento EE.10.1.0, it was completing order because I had downloadable product in my cart and there is no need to generate shipment for this. That's why it's status was "complete". :) :)